# Is it possible to get the list of applications accessing a table in SQL Server or Oracle from a query?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement to get the list of applications accessing a table in SQL Server or Oracle from a query. Is it possible to display the details with a query?

Comment: On SQL Server you could have a look at the Default trace; or if it doesn't have the details set a new one up. Note, however, that SQL Server only captures the Application's name if it is passed in the connection string. If it isn't, then SQL Server has little idea of the source.

Comment: A list of applications accessing a table? What do you mean by "accessing?" I think the best you'll be able to do is get information about users currently connected to the server or currently querying your table.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from what do you mean for "application". In Sql Server, in SQL Profiler Tool, there is client_app_name column in trace monitor, that contains the client type (ex. .Net CLient Provider, SQL Management Studio ..). If you haven't define a custom log in the application, I think that is difficult to retrieve more detailed informations